# Javascript Nested-Array throwing 'TypeError' - Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a nested array in Javascript, but whatever I try to get something out of this array I get an error 'TypeError'. Here is the code snippet:

```
        var domains =new Array();
        var keyPair =new Array();
function displayStorage(){
    var i = 0;
    var sKey;
    while ((sKey = window.localStorage.key(i))) {
        keyPair[i] = localStorage.key(i) + localStorage.getItem(sKey);
        i++;
    }
    keyPair.sort(sorter());
    siteCount = 0;
    valueCount = 0;
    while(siteCount < keyPair.length / 4) {
        var offset = keyPair[siteCount].length - 1;
        domains[siteCount] =new Array[keyPair.length];
        //keyPair[siteCount].substr(0,offset) keyPair[siteCount].substr(-1);
        domains[siteCount][valueCount] = keyPair[valueCount];
        valueCount++;
    if(valueCount >= 4){
        valueCount = 0;
    }
        siteCount++;
    }
}
document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML = domains[0][1];
```

I have tried without the if statement inside too. As well as swapping

`domains[siteCount][valueCount]`

for `domains[siteCount,valueCount]`

I have also tried replacing the while with this for loop:

```
for( siteCount; siteCount <= keyPair; siteCount++){
    domains[siteCount] =new Array();
    for(valueCount;valueCount < keyPair; valueCount++){
        domains[siteCount][valueCount] = keyPair[siteCount];
    }
}
```

I understand from reading around the web what the TypeError message means 'Represents an error when a value is not of the expected type.' Although I can't understand why it would be occurring on this occasion 
I just can't see what the problem is.

Thanks for any help,
Wez.

Comment: I've tried to put your code into a JSFiddle and its giving all sorts of errors, 1st it bombs when you try to access window.localStorage.key(i) and i > than items in the storage, I quickly put try/catch round that to test further, theres no sorter function so commented out the sort then i gate new Array[keyPair.length] is not a constructor, can you please put together a JSFiddle to show the fault your having

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
keyPair.sort(sorter());
```

You should be passing the function, not evaluating the function.  Like so:

```
keyPair.sort(sorter);
```